# Apply CSS to printWindow.print(); in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a section in an HTML page that I need to print. I use the following JS method to print it.

```
printWindow.print();
```

This is how I do it.

```
$("#toprint").on("click", function () {

            var divContents = $("#tobebilled").html();
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');

printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/print.css"/>'); 
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Bill</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
```

The problem is that i use 3 css files

```
Custom.min.css
bootstrap.min.css
components.min.css
```

In my print out, I cant seem to have applied these styles. The print is coming out raw. How can I apply CSS?

Answer (score 2):

```
printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/print.css"/>')
```

this includes print.css.

do the same for the other css files with proper path to the files